# How do I remove all single quotes in all files recursively using `rename`?

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, special-characters

The title says it all and yes I know there are many questions similar, but the closest I could find was removing " and not '. What I've tried so far is:

```
find -name "*'*" -type f | rename 's/\'//g'
```

or `rename 's/[']//g'` and some other variations.
I find all the files, but when I'm piping it to `rename`, I'm just getting `>`for prompt and have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to return. I've recently changed a lot of files with this, and it has worked like a charm on any special character, except the single quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use double quotes:

```
rename -n "s/'//g"
```

remove `-n` after testing to rename the files for real

Use `-exec` though...

```
find -name "*'*" -type f -exec rename -n "s/'//g" '{}' \;
```

If the list is not too long, make it faster...

```
find -name "*'*" -type f -exec rename -n "s/'//g" '{}' +
```

Or, as suggested in comments, use recursive shell globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n "s/'//g" **/*"'"*
```

You can use `shopt -u globstar` to turn recursive globbing with `**` off, but it will be off anyway when you start a new shell.

Comment: The `rename` command has its own file globbing syntax, so there's likely no need for the `find` command here.

Comment: @TomRussell oh really? I don't know about that - I use the shell to glob with `rename` (there is `globstar` which would presumably work here). Would you care to post an answer to demonstrate?

Comment: The final parameter is the standard shell globbing: 
`Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...`

Comment: Oops. I neglected to consider the recursive aspect of the OP's question.

Comment: @TomRussell that output looks like it comes from the other `rename` ([rename.ul](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html)) command to me. I am not familiar with that command, but I did not find anything about `rename` having *its own* globbing syntax (the way `find` does). Bash has `globstar` which makes `**` recursive, but one has to quote the single quote again... `shopt -s globstar; rename -n "s/'//g" **/*"'"*` is working for me in Bash 5.0.17

Comment: Cool stuff. My shell foo is rather weak. :-)

Comment: @TomRussell thanks for pointing the way to a findless version. I added it to the answer :)

Comment: Nice touch telling how to turn off `globstar`. So are you using `bash`? I get "rename: not enough arguments".

Comment: This works on my system: `$ rename "'" '' **`. The 3 args are: "'", '' and **, telling `rename` to replace the quote with the empty string and do so recursively.

Comment: @TomRussell that is the other rename command which has different syntax. This question is about the perl rename command. I am not familiar with the other one. Yes, using Bash. I don't know what other shells have globstar

Comment: Correct. It's about the bash builtin. I don't see Perl mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TomRussell my Bash doesn't have a `rename` builtin, according to `type -a`. I call this `rename` Perl rename because it is a Perl script and uses Perl expressions. In Ubuntu, it is either installed by default, or available from the `rename` package. The other rename comes from the `util-linux` package and on Ubuntu we need to call it with `rename.ul` to prevent confusion. Syntax of OP's command, and the fact that they're calling `rename` not `rename.ul` on Ubuntu, strongly suggests the rename they're talking about is the Perl one (your answer may help others though)

Comment: Well, I'll be darned! :-) I'm not familiar with Ubuntu but wouldn't have expected such a difference between bash shells. I wonder what the reasoning for the difference might be. I'd have to suppose that maybe the Perl command is a more capable wrapper around the shell binary.

Answer (score 0):

This works with `bash` on my system (OpenSUSE Leap):

```bash
$ rename "'" '' **
```

The 3 args to `rename` are: `"'"`, `''` and `**` (`globstar`), telling it to replace the quote with the empty string and do so recursively.

Note that `**` (`globstar`) is turned on by default on my system. I'm not aware of a way to turn it off.